# No desktop on 14.04

Tags: upgrade

I have upgraded from 12.04 to 14.04 and I am unable to go to the desktop. I get stuck at tty.

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop results in:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
ubuntu-desktop is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 292 not upgraded.
-desktop:~$
```

Answer (score 2):

There are packages which aren't updated.
Try running the following from terminal:

```
sudo -s
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
reboot
```

Comment: No didn't work. After rebooting I still get tty. However, I am able to log in through GNU GRUB [Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-57-generic (recovery mode)]

Comment: I wonder if there is an easier way to do it than through GNU/GRUB